# How to group by one column then convert the other column into vectors?

Tags: r

For example, my df now is:

```
person <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
score <- c(31,2,13,5,6,7,8,9,4)
df <- data.frame(person,score)
```

what I want to get is a two-column table with three rows.

```
[1,1]="a", [1,2]= a vector of c(31,2,13)
[2,1]="b", [2,2]= a vector of c(5,6,7)
[3,1]="c", [3,2]= a vector of c(8,9,4)
```

Actually, I just want the three vectors to perform another function but I tried something like the following code, it didn't work(the actual function is much more complex but it takes in two vectors of the same length where one is provided).

```
f <- function(x,y){x-y}
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(person) %>% 
    summarise(diff = f(c(1,2,3), score))
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The code provided works and returns 3 values for each `person` which is what `f` does. What were you expecting to happen ?

Comment: i want it to give a similar table with only one row for each person and the output of 3 values as one vector in the second column:)

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the answer below you can save them in a list. `...summarise(diff = list(f(c(1,2,3), score)))`

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
aggregate(
  score ~ person,
  df,
  list
)
```

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  summarise(score = list(score))
```

Comment: @Ayemeng please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem.